How to fix the error ValueError: Expected input batch_size (49) to match target batch_size (64)
I keep modifying the dataloader side, but it still shows that error.
This is the preprocessing code:
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
from torchvision import transforms


class ImageDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, images, labels, transform=None, target_transform=None):
        self.images = images
        self.labels = labels
        self.transform = transform
        self.target_transform = target_transform

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.images)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        image = self.images[idx]
        label = self.labels[idx]

        if self.transform:
            image = self.transform(image)

        if self.target_transform:
            label = self.target_transform(label)

        return image, label

# resize the data
resize_transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize((0.5,), (0.5,))
])

# using Data Loader, is a function that wraps the Dataset and outputs each data using a mini-batch.
train_dataset = ImageDataset(images=x, labels=y, transform=resize_transform)
train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)

# print each data (x test and y test in dataloader)
for images, labels in train_dataloader:
    print(images.shape)
    print(labels.shape)
    break

and this one is the model:
val_dataset = ImageDataset(x_val, y_val, transform=resize_transform)
val_loader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=64, shuffle=False)

import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim

class Network(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Network, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 32, 3)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 3)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(64 * 16 * 16, 128)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, 64)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(64, 16)  # Adjusted for 16 classes

        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = x.view(-1, 64 * 16 * 16)  # Flatten layer
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x

# Define the loss function and optimizer
net = Network()
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)

# Training the model
num_epochs = 10
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    net.train()
    running_loss = 0.0
    for i, data in enumerate(train_dataloader, 0):
        inputs, labels = data
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = net(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        running_loss += loss.item()
    
    print(f"Epoch [{epoch + 1}/{num_epochs}], Loss: {running_loss / len(train_dataloader):.4f}")

    # Validation accuracy
    net.eval()
    correct = 0
    total = 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for inputs, labels in val_loader:
            outputs = net(inputs)
            _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
            total += labels.size(0)
            correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()

    accuracy = 100 * correct / total
    print(f"Validation Accuracy: {accuracy:.2f}%")

print("Finished Training")


And this mentioned error above keeps appearing:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[11], line 42
     40 optimizer.zero_grad()
     41 outputs = net(inputs)
---> 42 loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
     43 loss.backward()
     44 optimizer.step()

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:1736, in Module._wrapped_call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1734     return self._compiled_call_impl(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[misc]
   1735 else:
-> 1736     return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:1747, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1742 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1743 # this function, and just call forward.
   1744 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
   1745         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1746         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1747     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1749 result = None
   1750 called_always_called_hooks = set()

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\loss.py:1293, in CrossEntropyLoss.forward(self, input, target)
   1292 def forward(self, input: Tensor, target: Tensor) -> Tensor:
-> 1293     return F.cross_entropy(
   1294         input,
   1295         target,
   1296         weight=self.weight,
   1297         ignore_index=self.ignore_index,
   1298         reduction=self.reduction,
   1299         label_smoothing=self.label_smoothing,
   1300     )

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py:3479, in cross_entropy(input, target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce, reduction, label_smoothing)
   3477 if size_average is not None or reduce is not None:
   3478     reduction = _Reduction.legacy_get_string(size_average, reduce)
-> 3479 return torch._C._nn.cross_entropy_loss(
   3480     input,
   3481     target,
   3482     weight,
   3483     _Reduction.get_enum(reduction),
   3484     ignore_index,
   3485     label_smoothing,
   3486 )

ValueError: Expected input batch_size (49) to match target batch_size (64).

What is the problem here and how to resolve it?
I tried modifying dataloader.

I believe your problem might be arising from the last batch having fewer samples than the specified batch size (64), because the total number of samples is not divisible by 64. You might have to do something like this:
train_dataloader = DataLoader(
    train_dataset, 
    batch_size=64, 
    shuffle=True,
    drop_last=True  # This prevents the last incomplete batch
)

See the official documentation for more details.
On the other hand, I assume your first dimension is the batch dimension. If your x array is going through these changes in the forward() method of your Network(nn.Module) class: torch.Size([64, 1, 64, 64]) -> torch.Size([64, 32, 31, 31]) -> torch.Size([64, 64, 14, 14]) -> torch.Size([49, 16384]) -> torch.Size([49, 128]) -> torch.Size([49, 64]) -> torch.Size([49, 16]), you can see that the first dimension (batch) starts with 64 and ends up being 49, the flattening being likely the problem. I advice you to get the batch dimension out in the first line, doing something like this: batch_size = x.size(0) and then, do x = x.view(batch_size, -1) to flatten, instead of x = x.view(-1, 64 * 16 * 16), which hardcodes values.

I tried it but it doesn't work.. It still shows same error

Can you print the shape of x after each operation in the forward() method to see whether they match what you expect?

Yes this is the printed result:
Input shape: torch.Size([64, 1, 64, 64])
After conv1 and pool: torch.Size([64, 32, 31, 31])
After conv2 and pool: torch.Size([64, 64, 14, 14])
After flattening: torch.Size([49, 16384])
After fc1: torch.Size([49, 128])
After fc2: torch.Size([49, 64])
After fc3 (output): torch.Size([49, 16])

I edited the answer to include that. Let me know if this works.
